# как явно указать, какую версию MongoDB установить в Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

всем привет.
для установки Монги я использую команду

```
apt install -y mongodb
```

но она устанавливает последнюю версию. как явно указать, что я хочу 3.0, допустим.
спасибо.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-the-mongodb-packages

Answer (score 3):

### **Install MongoDB on Ubuntu**

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
```

---

```
sudo apt-get update
```

---

```
sudo apt-cache show mongodb-org | grep Version
```

---

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

### Docs..

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/administration/install-on-linux/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---